# Construct document-term matrix via Java and MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

**Background:**

I’m trying to make a “document-term” matrix in Java on Hadoop using MapReduce. A document-term matrix is like a huge table where each row represents a document and each column represents a possible word/term.

**Problem Statement:**

Assuming that I already have a term index list (so that I know which term is associated with which column number), what is the best way to look up the index for each term in each document so that I can build the matrix row-by-row (i.e., document-by-document)?

So far I can think of two approaches:

**Approach #1:**

Store the term index list on the Hadoop distributed file system. Each time a mapper reads a new document for indexing, spawn a new MapReduce job -- one job for each unique word in the document, where each job queries the distributed terms list for its term. This approach sounds like overkill, since I am guessing there is some overhead associated with starting up a new job, and since this approach might call for tens of millions of jobs. Also, I’m not sure if it’s possible to call a MapReduce job within another MapReduce job.

**Approach #2:**

Append the term index list to each document so that each mapper ends up with a local copy of the term index list. This approach is pretty wasteful with storage (there will be as many copies of the term index list as there are documents). Also, I’m not sure how to merge the term index list with each document -- would I merge them in a mapper or in a reducer?

***Question Update 1***

**Input File Format:**

The input file will be a CSV (comma separated value) file containing all of the documents (product reviews). There is no column header in the file, but the values for each review appear in the following order: product_id, review_id, review, stars. Below is a fake example:

> “Product A”, “1”,“Product A is very, very expensive.”,”2”
>
> “Product G”, ”2”, “Awesome product!!”, “5”

**Term Index File Format:**

Each line in the term index file consists of the following: an index number, a tab, and then a word. Each possible word is listed only once in the index file, such that the term index file is analogous to what could be a list of primary keys (the words) for an SQL table. For each word in a particular document, my tentative plan is to iterate through each line of the term index file until I find the word. The column number for that word is then defined as the column/term index associated with that word. Below is an example of the term index file, which was constructed using the two example product reviews mentioned earlier.

> 1 awesome
>
> 2 product
>
> 3 a
>
> 4 is
>
> 5 very
>
> 6 expensive

**Output File Format:**

I would like the output to be in the “Matrix Market” (MM) format, which is the industry standard for compressing matrices with many zeros. This is the ideal format because most reviews will contain only a small proportion of all possible words, so for a particular document it is only necessary to specify the non-zero columns.

The first row in the MM format has three tab separated values: the total number of documents, the total number of word columns, and the total number of lines in the MM file excluding the header. After the header, each additional row contains the matrix coordinates associated with a particular entry, and the value of the entry, in this order: reviewID, wordColumnID, entry (how many times this word appears in the review). For more details on the Matrix Market format, see this link: http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html.

Each review’s ID will equal its row index in the document-term matrix. This way I can preserve the review’s ID in the Matrix Market format so that I can still associate each review with its star rating. My ultimate goal -- which is beyond the scope of this question -- is to build a natural language processing algorithm to predict the number of stars in a new review based on its text.

Using the example above, the final output file would look like this (I can't get Stackoverflow to show tabs instead of spaces):

> 2 6   7
>
> 1 2   1
>
> 1 3   1
>
> 1 4   1
>
> 1 5   2
>
> 1 6   1
>
> 2 1   1
>
> 2 2   1

Comment: If you can put some examples of how the input dataset(table), the term index list file and output file should looks like, it would be helpful. Your problem seems interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @JtheRocker I've added clarifying details per your request.

Comment: So, how are you comparing the input file with the term index file? Please describe your term index file too.

Comment: @JtheRocker I've updated the "Term Index File Format:" section. Let me know if you would like additional details.

Comment: By word columns you mean your indexes in term list corresponds and and limited to ->'Product A is very, very expensive', 'Awesome product!!'

Comment: @JtheRocker Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use something analogous to a inverted index concept.

I'm suggesting this becaue, I'm assuming both the files are big. Hence, comparing each other like one-to-one would be real performance bottle neck.

Here's a way that can be used -

You can feed both the Input File Format csv file(s) (say, datafile1, datafile2) and the term index file (say, term_index_file) as input to your job.

Then in each mapper, you filter the source file name, something like this -

**Pseudo code for mapper -**

```
map(key, row, context){
  String filename= ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
   if (filename.startsWith("datafile") {

     //split the review_id, words from row
     ....
     context.write(new Text("word), new Text("-1 | review_id"));

   } else if(filename.startsWith("term_index_file") {
     //split index and word
     ....
     context.write(new Text("word"), new Text("index | 0"));
   }

}
```

**e.g. output from different mappers**

```
Key       Value      source
product   -1|1       datafile
very       5|0       term_index_file
very      -1|1       datafile
product   -1|2       datafile
very      -1|1       datafile
product    2|0       term_index_file
...
...
```

**Explanation (the example):** 
As it clearly shows the key will be your word and the value will be made of two parts separated by a delimiter **"|"**

If the source is a datafile then you emit key=product and value=-1|1, where -1 is a dummy element and 1 is a review_id.

If the source is a term_index_file then you emit key=product and value=2|0, where 2 is a index of word **'product'** and 0 is a dummy review_id, which we would use for sorting-   explained later.

Definitely, no duplicate index will be processed by two different mappers if we are providing the term_index_file as a normal input file to the job.
So,  **'product, vary'** or any other indexed word in the term_index_file will only be available to one mapper. Note this is only valid for term_index_file not the datafile.

**Next step:**

Hadoop mapreduce framework, as you might well know, will group by keys
So, you will have something like this going to different reducers,

```
reduce-1: key=product, value=<-1|1, -1|2, 2|0>
reduce-2: key=very, value=<5|0, -1|1, -1|1>
```

But, we have a problem in the above case. We would want a sort in the values after '|' i.e. in the `reduce-1 -> 2|0, -1|1, -1|2 and in reduce-2 -> <5|0, -1|1, -1|1>`

**To achieve that you can use a secondary sort implemented using a sort comparator. Please google for this but [here's a link](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/) that might help. Mentioning it here can go real lengthy.**

In each reduce-1, since the values are sorted as above, when we begin iteration, we would get the **'0'** in the first iteration and with it the **index_id=2**, which could then be used for subsequent iterations. In the next two iteration, we get review ids 1 and 2 consecutively, and we use a counter, so that we could keep track of any repeated review ids. When we get repeated review ids that would mean that a word appeared twice in the same review_id row. We reset the counter only when we find a different review_id and emit the previous review_id details for the particular index_id, something like this -

```
previous_review_id  + "\t" + index_id + "\t" + count
```

When the loop ends, we'll be left with a single previous_review_id, which we finally emit in the same fashion.

**Pseudo code for reducer -**

```
reduce(key, Iterable values, context) {
  String index_id = null;
  count = 1;
  String previousReview_id = null;
  for(value: values) {
      Split split[] = values.split("\\|");
      ....

      //when consecutive review_ids are same, we increment count
      //and as soon as the review_id differ, we emit, reset the counter and print
      //the previous review_id detected.
      if (split[0].equals("-1") && split[1].equals(previousReview_id)) {
          count++;
      } else if(split[0].equals("-1") && !split[1].equals(prevValue)) {
          context.write(previousReview_id + "\t" + index_id + "\t" + count);
          previousReview_id = split[1];//resting with new review_id id
          count=1;//resetting count for new review_id
      } else {
         index_id = split[0]; 
      }
  }
  //the last  previousReview_id will be left out, 
  //so, writing it now after the loop  completion
  context.write(previousReview_id + "\t" + index_id + "\t" + count);

}
```

This job is done with multiple reducers in order to leverage Hadoop for what it best known for - performance, as a result, the final output will be scattered, something like the following, deviating from your desired output.

```
1 4 1
2 1 1
1 5 2
1 2 1
1 3 1
1 6 1
2 2 1
```

But, if you want everything to be sorted according to the review_id (as your desired outpout), you can write one more job that will do that for your using a **single reducer** and the output of the previos job as input. And also at the same time calculate **2 6 7** and put it at the front of the output.

This is just an approach ( or an idea), I think, that might help you. You definitely want to modify this, put a better algorithm and use it the your way that you think would benefit you.

You can also use Composite keys for better clarity than using a delimiter such as "|".

I am open for any clarification. Please ask if you think, it might be useful to you.

Thank you!

Comment: I have to admit, it took me a long time to fully understand your code, and I was skeptical at first, but after re-reading it a few times it now finally makes a lot of sense. The link you provided was especially helpful, and made me think about the problem differently -- I hadn't thought of using a secondary sort, a sort comparator, and a composite key -- that's much more graceful than what I had originally planned. I'm also thankful that you got the Market Matrix part figured out. Your answer has saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Welcome. To my eyes, the problem was interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the term index list in Hadoop distributed cache so that it is available to mappers and reducers. For instance, in Hadoop streaming, you can run your job as follows:

```
$ hadoop  jar $HADOOP_INSTALL/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar \
  -input myInputDirs \
  -output myOutputDir \
  -mapper myMapper.py \
  -reducer myReducer.py \
  -file myMapper.py \
  -file myReducer.py \
  -file myTermIndexList.txt
```

Now in myMapper.py you can load the file myTermIndexList.txt and use it to your purpose. If you give a more detailed description of your input and desired output I can give you more details.

Comment: I think this is a good start. I didn't know there was something called "distributed cache". Now I'm looking into it. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Approach #1 is not good but very common if you don't have much hadoop experience. Starting jobs is very expensive. What you are going to want to do is have 2-3 jobs that feed each other to get the desired result. A common solution to similar problems is to have the mapper tokenize the input and output pairs, group them in the reducer executing some kind of calculation and then feed that into job 2. In the mapper in job 2 you invert the data in some way and in the reducer do some other calculation.

I would highly recommend learning more about Hadoop through a training course. Interestingly Cloudera's dev course has a very similar problem to the one you are trying to address. Alternatively or perhaps in addition to a course I would look at "Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce" specifically the sections on "COMPUTING RELATIVE FREQUENCIES" and "Inverted Indexing for Text Retrieval"

http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf